# What type of insect is this?

Tags: entomology, species-identification

I'm naturally thinking this is a bee, but I cannot find it anywhere in any insect identifiers. I caught this picture on top of my doorway, it's about 1 1/2 inches in length, and its torso seems to be coated in a layer of hair, and the rest of its body is narrow. The thick layer of hair may or may not be accurate, I didn't want to get too close to it, but that's how it appeared at least.

[image: Unidentified Insect]
[image]
[image]

What is this?

PS - Found in Kentucky, and I'm not sure why one pic shows wings and the other one doesn't...

Comment: Well I can suggest why the wings are not seen in two of the pictures. From the shadows it is obvious you have not used the flash. Under natural low light the shutter remains open for a longer time and any movement of the wings will blur it. In the third picture you must have got when the wings were not moving.

Comment: Well I was using a camera phone

Comment: It's a red-footed robber fly, check out those lateral stripes and the red/yellow leg segments

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the general body plan, it looks like it's probably a [robber fly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asilidae). Here's a [page of specifically Kentucky robber flies](http://www.uky.edu/Ag/CritterFiles/casefile/insects/flies/robber/robber.htm) – it's possible yours could be a Bearded Robber Fly.

Comment: That looks about right

Comment: It is most certainly a Robber Fly. I would agree with Oreotrephes that it is a Bearded. I can't seem to find anything closer.

Comment: My first idea as well, but the picture is probably to unclear for a certain species determination.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I would say that is a bearded robber fly. Robber flies are similar to dragonflies in that they catch prey by catching it in midair. They will attack mostly bees, wasps, and hornets, and I have seen many catching bumblebees in the wild. I have even seen some sit near a yellow jacket nest and catch a hornet when it comes out. They suck out the juices of their prey with a proboscis using methods similar to spiders. They will also bite when handled, as I have found out through experience.

Answer (score 0):

It is commonly called as "Robber fly" or "assassin fly". Scientifically it is "Asilidae" of the order "Diptera" and it is a fast attacking predator mostly preying on grasshopper nymphs and damsel flies. It is strongly built for kill.
http://www.robberflies.info/keyger/htmle/didpic.html

Comment: Can you provide some references for your answer? Please read the help for this site, in particular [here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) where you can know how to write a good answer.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asilidae

Comment: Also posting a separate image of your ID is important to allow other usres assess your answer