# Help identify this red/black Vietnamese insect

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found this strange insect while on Son Tra, Da Nang in central Vietnam. It was about 4cm long and although it was on the ground, was obviously capable of flying. I've never seen anything like this and would like help identifying it, please. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It looks very much like a robber fly. I'm voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What type of insect is this?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10022/what-type-of-insect-is-this)

Comment: The duplication is taxonomic only, not geographic (but a brief search found few images of live robber flies from Vietnam, so going deeper is best considered problematic).

Comment: That is not a duplicate, the species is clearly different. The only thing those questions have in common is the Family being [Asilidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asilidae)

Answer (score 2):

*Dasypogon* is a genus of [**robber flies**](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/beneficial/flies/robber_flies.htm) in the family *Asilidae*.

- Kingdom: Animalia
- Phylum: Arthropoda
- Class: Insecta
- Order: Diptera ,
- Family: Asilidae
- Tribe:Dasypogonini
- Genus:Dasypogon.

84 species belong to the genus *Dasypogon*. Among these, this one is *Asilidae Dasypogon diadema*.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the link. Could you link the site to the picture as well - it looks like the same image btw ? It's best practice to dig up an image form a reputable website to show the positive ID. I took the liberty to clean up your post a bit. Thanks for your contribution. +1

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! According to several sources this is a European species and not found in Vietnam. In general, you are more likely to get a positive response to your answer if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. ——— You may also wish to take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you! 